# Jenkins shell script unexpected end of file

Tags: shell, docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I started a new `Jenkins` server in the following way using `Docker`:

```
$ docker run -p 8081:8080 -p 50000:50000 -v "${PWD}"/jenkins:/var/jenkins_home -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -d --name jenkins jenkins/jenkins:lts
```

I want to use it for a simple pipeline executing a shell script that is building another Docker container. This is why I am mounting the `docker.sock` as well. However, using a Jenkinsfile like the following:

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                echo "####### builds: #######"
                sh "(exit 1) || true # whatever I write here, it always fails"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I always get an error like:

```
Print Message -- ####### builds: ####### -- (self time 7ms)
####### builds: ####### 

Shell Script -- (exit 1) || true -- (self time 18s)
[X's Pipeline] Running shell script sh: 1: Syntax error: end of file unexpected (expecting "done")
process apparently never started in /var/jenkins_home/workspace/X's Pipeline@tmp/durable-f294beff
```

replacing the `sh` line by any of the following did produce a similar error message and lead the build process to fail as well:

- `sh "pwd;"`
- `sh "echo 'hello';"`
- `sh ./build.sh;"`
- ​

  ````
  sh ```
  #!/bin/sh
  echo hello
  ```
  ````
- … I tried many more

But when I remove the `sh` line, the build succeeds.
I have successfully done this before on other systems. Is there anything I am missing here?

---

```
  Operating System: CentOS Linux 7 (Core)
       CPE OS Name: cpe:/o:centos:centos:7
            Kernel: Linux 3.10.0-514.26.2.el7.x86_64
      Architecture: x86-64

    Docker version: 17.05.0-ce, build 89658be
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It turned out, the name of the pipeline `X's Pipeline` has an `'`; and Jenkins is not escaping it or warning the user when using the GUI **!!!!!!**. After renaming the pipeline to `X Pipeline` it works just fine. Knowing this before could have saved me hours of trouble…

Comment: Holy cow. I just hit that too and it was driving me bonkers. Not sure I ever would have found the problem had I not seen this! I can't believe they don't just disallow apostrophes in project names unless they can handle them correctly. :/